# Refresh gives error after deployment (MERN)

Tags: express, deployment, react-router-dom, mern

I have created a full MERN stack app, and deployed it. However, when I redirect the user to a different react route in the front-end, and then refresh the page, I receive an error. It gives me the url is not found. How do I account for the front-end url in the backend? For example, in the front-end, when a user logs in, they are re-directed to say `/transactions` react route, and once the route page is loaded, I fetch the transactions from the backend for that user at the `/api/v1/transactions` endpoint in the server.

I tried to serve the `index.html` at any url by writing the following:

```
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

instead of

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

but this doesn't work for me, as when I am in the `/transactions` route when I refresh, instead of fetching the transactions from the endpoint `/api/v1/transactions` and put the results in Redux state, the `index.html` page is fetched instead and put in the state, and the logic on the fetched data gives error, because it's not the expected data. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Make that the *last* route defined, and/or make sure it only handles appropriate requests (e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/blob/16a25eda790483ff193e3b7042a520d1586eab4c/server/middleware.js?ts=2#L31-L36, where I've written to only respond to GET requests that aren't to the API root).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! That was my mistake. It worked perfectly!